Exploring Parent-Child Dependencies in Spring Batch: Leveraging Data Flow between Steps
I'm trying to figure out how to leverage Spring Batch to execute a step that depends on a parent step, which provides data to the child, and the child returns it.
The flow I'd like to build is as follows:
Schema
The crucial aspect is that in step 3, I need to be able to provide the child step with a class of type T, and at the end of the child step's lifecycle, in step 9, it returns a data of type K to the processor.
Is it possible to synthesize this flow somehow using Spring Batch's jobs or other tools?
I would like to extend my heartfelt gratitude in advance to anyone who can lend a hand or provide some guidance on the issue. Your assistance is immensely appreciated.
StepBuilder per writer post-step
